# How to use SQL in Oracle to remove duplicate id

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following records from a table. I would like to use SQL in Oracle 9, 10, 11 to do my task.

```
1040    1040a   1040e   tax_id
                   Y    111
            Y           111
                   Y    4444
            Y           4444
Y                       4344
                   Y    4344
```

How do I use SQL in Oracle to pull my desired output like below:

```
1040    1040a   1040e   tax_id
            Y   Y       111
            Y   Y       4444
Y               Y       4344
```

I am running the SQL in Oracle version 9/10g/11g.

Thanks for your help.
HT

Answer (score 2):

Looks like simple `Group by` with `Max` Aggregate should do the trick

```
SELECT Max(1040),
       Max(1040a),
       Max(1040e),
       tax_id
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY tax_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT tax_id, 1040, 1040a, 1040e
FROM
(
    SELECT tax_id, 1040
    FROM table
) A
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT tax_id, 1040a
    FROM table
) B
ON A.tax_id=B.tax_id
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT tax_id, 1040e
    FROM table
) C
ON A.tax_id=C.tax_id
/
```